# Would it be possible to create a UiPath Custom Activity using Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, uipath

In UiPath you can create Custom Activities using C# code as seen [here](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/creating-a-custom-activity). I dont know much about C# and I was wondering if anyone has any clue how or if its even possible to create a custom activity with Powershell and how I would do that.

Finally, any insight on how I could wrap up the code (and Im assuming corresponding dlls) into a nuGet package  would be immensely helpful. Thank you in advance!

I've tried with C#. I got it to work, but as I try to do more complex things, Id like to know if I could leverage powershell as I am much more familiar with it.

Comment: Why not using the [PackageManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6) from PowerShell itself and simply using the UIPath [Invoke-PowerShell](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/invoke-power-shell) activity

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked contains a step-by-step guide. You can't use PowerShell to create custom activities, you will need Visual Studio and C#. There is the free [Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) available that you can use, but check whether the [terms apply](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/).

With VS installed, you would go ahead an create a new class library - just follow [their guide](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/creating-a-custom-activity).

When your activity is done you would need to deploy it as a NuGet Package, and you can use the [Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/releases) to do so. This is were you would "wrap up" all binaries created - they become part of said package.

However, since you mentioned PowerShell - not knowing your precise requirements, of course - there is an activity dedicated to executing PowerShell commands in UiPath: the [Invoke PowerShell](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/invoke-power-shell) activity. If you're already familiar with PS, if you have plenty of scripts lying around, just use this activity.

Comment: I guess what I'd like to be able to do is somehow leverage a powershell script that leverages dlls without having to reference via filepaths those dlls or the script itself. Id like to be able to package all that up and send arguments through to be processed by the powershell script. I have to use 'Read Text File' for complex Powershell scripts, meaning.....I need a text file. Thoughts on how to leverage packaged PS scripts?

Comment: Not an expert on PS, but wouldn't it be possible to write your own cmdlets and then call them with Invoke PowerShell from the workflow in UiPath?

Comment: Can we use other languages than c# to create a Custom activity? like Java or Python

Comment: @WolfgangRadl yes you can, but the moment you want to do anything near complex that strategy breaks down. Especially if you want to leverage dlls. Im not aware of how to package up powershell with dll and even if I did that, I would still have to drag it along with my project as a reference as opposed to it being an integrated part of it.

Comment: @NovaPrice I see.. on That case I would recommend moving forward with a custom activity with all dependent dolls becoming part of this package. You could call powershell from within this activity (i.e. you class).

Comment: @AbhishekVaidya in theory, any CLI language should be fine. Note that CodeActivity is part of the framework, but afaik not of .net core.